# Set CSS aspect ratio to the inverse of width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having trouble with a CSS layout - the key part is that I'd like a box to grow in height as its width decreases.

Now, I've started with the 'fixed aspect ratio' technique on an element - where you set the height to 0, and the padding-top to a percentage, say 50%. The padding value is calculated as 50% of the *width* of the parent element (not the height, as you might guess), so what you end up with is a box with a fixed 2:1 aspect ratio, but otherwise is fluid in size.

The next step (in my half-baked solution) is to modify the padding percentage so it increases as the width decreases (the width is 100% of the page). I'm pretty sure this can't happen in straight CSS, and I'm happy with a small piece of Javascript to update the value when the window is resized.

Can anyone help me with the formula to adjust that percentage inversely to the width?

A few other notes:

- The element is a 'spacer' - it will be invisible, so if it takes two elements, etc. that's OK.
- The whole layout is fluid and responsive from 2500+ px wide down to 320px, so there's no 'max value' we can use (I don't think).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you possibly put the coding you have thus far into (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: +1 for a fun question :) Idk yet if my answer is what you were looking for, but it was fun to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the jQuery .resize() function might be of assistance? it binds a function to whenever the element (or window) is resized.

For example, if you wanted the area of an element `#el` to always be 50,000 pixels-squared

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    area = 50000;
    width = $('#el').width();
    $('#el').height(Math.ceil(area/width));
    });
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/T8HrW/embedded/result/

Example Code: http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/T8HrW/

jQuery .resize() Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Let me know if this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: Bingo - the 'constant area' was the thing I was missing! Thanks, mate - I had the feeling that it was something simple, but after staring at it for ages I'd stopped being able to think about it!

Comment: I'm going to try an implementation of the same rule with CSS3's calc() where supported, with a jquery fallback like you've shown. I think my final solution will probably derive the area as a proportion of the viewport area, to keep it responsive...