# Setting width using .css method in jQuery with window re-size as condition

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, window-resize

In my template I want to set my `#wrapper` container width dynamically using jQuery, so for any screen resolution, `#wrapper` width will be `screen width - 200`.

```
var _width= ($(window).width() - 200) 
$("#wrapper").css("width",_width);
```

After setting this value, I want to change width dynamically on window re-size. I use the following jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    var _width_prcnt = (($(window).width()- (200)/($(window).width()/100) );
    $('#wrapper').stop(false,true).animate({
        'width':_width_prcnt+ '%'
    });
});
```

I think this doesn't work properly. How can I use an `if-else` statement so that the width is set once, and animating the width works only if there is window re-size?

Answer (score 2):

You should resize your window only with css. The window with:200px is easy with `margin`.

```
#wrapper{
min-width:500px;
margin:0 100px;
}
```

This is also centered.

Comment: I agree. Galexy: You could also use `min-width` and `max-width` and/or `media queries` if the width needs to be static at some point.

Comment: this possible with media queries, but I want to set my wrapper width dynamic on window re-size

Comment: Did you try the code above? You say you are looking for a simple css3 method, but when you are given simple css method, you seem to refuse it... Here's example of the above code (pretty much): http://jsfiddle.net/K3u2w/1/ and here's the same thing with jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/K3u2w/ ...am I holding your hand tightly enough?

Comment: This solution makes the width of the wrapper equal to the window's width. See my fiddle for this a demonstration. You'd rather try @Joonas solution, which is compatible with all browsers.

Comment: @Bigood I keep forgetting things.. You are absolutely right. I kept excluding `width: 100%;` in my head because it is unnecessary and I forgot that it actually ruins it because it forces 100% width and adds the margin to the sides... so, yea.

Comment: @joonas--> Actually css3 media quires set's width for particular set only , I wanna see my width changing even on single pixel re-size.

Comment: I have seen jsfiddle provided by you. just going through those help links. thanks friends

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS3's `calc()` to achieve this ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/calc)):

```
#wrapper{
    width:calc(100% - 200px);
    margin: 0 100px; //If you want the content centered
}
```

With `#wrapper` being the direct child of an element whose width is the window's width.

Please see [this chart](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) on caniuse.com for browser compatibility, and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/mBbCy/) for a working example.

Comment: Problem with this is lack of opera support.

Comment: Its looking simple with css3 method , But I don't know whether its works with all browser or not.

Comment: @galexy See the link on my updated answer for browser compatibility.

Comment: Thanks@Bigood - Nice chart for browser compatibility ,Actually this is a kind of responsive design and I can see on some devices with iOS and android browser this is not supporting.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery .resize() should work, I just answered another question a few minutes ago about it at [Set CSS aspect ratio to the inverse of width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918108/set-css-aspect-ratio-to-the-inverse-of-width/15918763#15918763). Check my answer + the linked fiddle to see if it gives you the functionality you're looking for. Let me know if my answer works for you, or let me know how .resize() doesn't fit and I'll try to give a better answer.